# Elementary question on inequality using $\;\liminf\;$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

In generall, if $\;x_n\;$ is a sequence of real numbers, then $\;\forall \epsilon \gt 0\;\exists N\in \mathbb N:\;x_n \gt \liminf x_n -\epsilon\;\;\forall n\gt N\;$

as you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior

Taking the above inequality into account, if $\;x_n(t)\;$ is a sequence of real integrable functions and $\;I\subset \mathbb R\;$ then, **is it true to claim that $\;\int_{I} x_n(t)\;dt \ge \liminf \int_{I} x_n(t)\;dt\;$?**

I think it should be valid if I set $\;y_n=\int_{I} x_n(t)\;dt\;$. However I'm quite unsure of this argument.

I would really appreciate if somebody could confirm or fix the above inequality in order to hold.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with $x_n(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I mean $\;x_n(x)\;$ is a sequence of real (integrable) functions. I edited it

Comment: I edited to remove the clash of variables in the symbols $x_n(x)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Using the variable $\;x\;$ here would be unnecessary confusing. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is false. Take $I=[0,1]$ and $x_n(t):=-1/n$ for all $t \in I$. Then $\int_I x_n=-1/n$ for all $n$, while $\liminf \int_I x_n=0$. The correct version is: for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that
$$
\forall n\ge N,\,\,\, \int_I x_n(t)\mathrm{d}t > \left(\liminf_{k\to \infty} \int_I x_k(t)\mathrm{d}t\right) -\varepsilon.
$$

However, you can be probably interested in the [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma).

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer! Could I ask you something more? If I considered $\;\epsilon=\int_{\mathbb R -I} x_n(t)\;dt \gt 0\;$, then would it be true to say:  $\;\forall n \ge N\;,\;\int_{I} x_n(t)\;dt \gt (\liminf_{k \to \infty} int_{I} x_k(t)\;dt)-\int_{\mathbb R -I} x_n(t)\;dt \Rightarrow \int_{\mathbb R} x_n(t)\;dt  \gt (\liminf_{k \to \infty} \int_{I} x_k(t)\;dt)\;$

Comment: No because the $x_n$s are functions $I\to \mathbf{R}$, hence $\int_{I^c} x_n$ would be undefined. Also, even if you define it on the whole $\mathbf{R}$, there is no reason to say that $\int_{I^c} x_n$ is positive. Lastly, even if you fix the previous two arguments, consider the case of constant functions $x_n(t)=0$ for all $n$ and all $t$; then, your last implication would be false.